# How to refer a class instance with a local variable?

Tags: typescript

```js
class A {
    x = 1;
};

let B = A;

function C(arg1: B){
    arg1.x
};
```

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/syntax/colletion-range.ts:10:18 
    TS2749: 'B' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing the class constructor using a variable will not also alias the type. Declaring a class produces both a value (the constructor) and a type (the instance type of the class).

You could define the type as well:

```
let B = A;
type B = A;
```

You could also get the type of the class stored in `B` using `typeof B` and then get the instance type using `InstanceType`:

```
class A {
    x = 1;
};

let B = A;

function C(arg1: InstanceType<typeof B>){
    arg1.x
};
```

Comment: hi, i have another question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392097/how-can-i-import-a-file-with-the-file-extension-is-xx, can you help me? thank you a lot.

Comment: @Michael_Lee looked at the question, webpack/awesome-typescript-loader not my area of expertise ..